# Replace 'page' twig template for controller/url

Tags: theming, 8

I have a page generated with custom controller. 
It's special page, so i need to remove all sidebars, headers and logo, for that page, and use custom design/layout.

How can i replace 'page' twig template for that url/controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create new twig template in the template folder of your theme `page--your-url.html.twig` and clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks, found it at page suggestions. Don't know how did i miss it there =) Spent 2 hours looking for some page_alter...

Comment: @Vovka If you enable Twig debug, template suggestions will be in the HTML output as comments.